# PostgreSQL: How to run query in parallel in function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, parallel-processing

I have a simple query

```
select bod_vykonu_kod, count(1)
from cdc_s5_zdroj
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

Which runs in parallel like it should.
Explain analyze: https://explain.depesz.com/s/auVt

Then if I put the same query in function it does not run in parallel. I tried it as **STABLE** or **VOLATILE** and still no parallel. I also added **PARALLEL SAFE** but no difference.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
test_par () 
returns table (
t_column1 bigint,
t_column2 bigint
)

volatile
PARALLEL SAFE
AS $dbvis$

BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
select bod_vykonu_kod, count(1)
from cdc_s5_zdroj
group by 1
order by 1 desc;

END;
$dbvis$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Explain analyze volatile: https://explain.depesz.com/s/glFO
Explain analyze stable: https://explain.depesz.com/s/vnXO
`Explain analyze stable and parallel safe:` https://explain.depesz.com/s/QlKM

> PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit
>   max_parallel_workers = 8
>   max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4

Am I doing something wrong or functions does not support parallel execution like this?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue with a plpgsql function.  RETURN QUERY never ran in parallel.  The only solution I could find was to do something like this, because `CREATE TABLE AS` **will** use parallel processing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
test_par () 
returns table (
t_column1 bigint,
t_column2 bigint
)

volatile
AS $dbvis$

BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp ON COMMIT DROP AS
select bod_vykonu_kod, count(1)
from cdc_s5_zdroj
group by 1
order by 1 desc;

RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM my_temp;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_temp;
END;
$dbvis$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

It's not ideal, but for my situation, it was still a lot faster than not using parallel processing.

Update: as of Postures 14, return query will now use parallel workers.  We no longer need to use the create table workaround.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is because processing can be suspended, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html). I have not verified this though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured as well, although it seems strange that they explicitly mention `FOR x IN query LOOP` and not `RETURN QUERY` which seems more common and less obvious to me.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  I don't think RETURN QUERY can actually be suspended, though.  It gathers its entire results before returning them, unlike FOR x IN QUERY.  This smells like a bug, or at least a mal-feature, someone might want to check with the mailing list. "The current implementation of RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY stores the entire result set before returning from the function, as discussed above." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Thank you it does work, though it is not the right solution in my case

Comment: Nice workaround, seems to work fine in my case

Answer (score 4):

I dug into the code to see why `RETURN QUERY` does not support parallel execution.

The reason is that it uses a cursor to fetch query result in batches of 50, and queries executed using a cursor are not run in parallel (because execution could be suspended).

This is the relevant code in function `exec_stmt_return_query` from `src/pl/plpgsql/src/pl_exec.c`:

```c
exec_stmt_return_query(PLpgSQL_execstate *estate,
                       PLpgSQL_stmt_return_query *stmt)
{
[...]
    if (stmt->query != NULL)
    {
        /* static query */
        exec_run_select(estate, stmt->query, 0, &portal);
    }
[...]
    while (true)
    {
        uint64      i;

        SPI_cursor_fetch(portal, true, 50);

[...]
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, though I must say this behaviour is quite unfortunate since I am using functions to encapsulate queries for our front-end. Hopefully in some future updates there will be some solution for this.

Comment: Write a complaint to the pgsql-hackers mailing list. That's what all the important people read.